# Plugin List Category: post custom field doesn’t show anything

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I'm using the Plugin List Category to show a list of posts and I use it with the parameters:

```
[catlist name=talleres thumbnail=yes thumbnail_size=52,52 excerpt=yes customfield_display=featured]
```

But it doesn't show anything for the custom fields. I tried with different parameters, still nothing. Does anyone have an idea, do I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: anyone can help me on this. why my customfields don't show??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still don't know what exactly fixed it. but now it's all right. 
i have also found another way to show custom fields: 
if you want to show a specific field in a specific place, in the CartListDisplayer.php, add to the function lcp_build_post anywhere you like: 
$lcp_display_output .= get_post_meta($single->ID, 'featured', true);

where featured is the name of yuor custom field. 
Hope it can help someone.